# Azure AD B2C - Populate username in custom login page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I use Azure AD B2C to authenticate users for my asp.net web application.  I have a customized sign-up-sign-in policy with custom login page.  Is it possible to store the username whenever the user gets redirected to the Azure custom login page ?  Also is there a way to pass the username to the custom login page ?

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br

Seems like its been planned

Comment: Can you explain your scenario better? Why do you want to capture the username, i.e. what do you want to do with it?

Comment: As for passing the username to the customer login page, you can use the login_hint query parameter, though this only works for local account as it doesn't make sense for social accounts.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario better? Why do you want to capture the username, i.e. what do you want to do with it? 
(A) This is related to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443865/azure-b2c-mfa-at-user-level-and-sign-in-policy-level ... I have two policies, one for MFA and one for non-MFA and in my database, I specify which user uses which policy.  I have an initial login screen in which the user enters the username.  Then with the username, I go to my database and grab the policy for that user and redirect the owin challenge accordingly.  This takes me to the Azure custom login page

Comment: When it does, I dont want the user to enter the username one more time and need to get it passed somehow

Comment: As for passing the username to the customer login page, you can use the login_hint query parameter, though this only works for local account as it doesn't make sense for social accounts.

(A) I am going to go ahead and try your suggestion with the login_hint

Comment: I was able to get the username passed on to the custom login screen using the login_hint

Comment: CaCoFoNiX - why doesn't this make sense for social accounts?  I don't want my users to have to enter their username for Facebook, either, if they've used it to access my app.

Comment: nhwilly - Can you give some background on your application and how the users are setup and how they login ?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do it with the help of azure functions

Comment: it would be more helpful if you can give example or link  to tutorial/blogpost explaining how this can be done