# New custom login page when use Azure AD as

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I am trying to use custom login page when using Azure AD but until now without success. I don't want to customize the login page offered by Azure, I want to use completely new login page. Is this possible?

I found some possible answers ([Redirect user to custom login page when using Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517925/redirect-user-to-custom-login-page-when-using-azure-ad) and [Azure AD B2C - Populate username in custom login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680972/azure-ad-b2c-populate-username-in-custom-login-page)) but and the owner of these questions still doesn't find the correct answer.

Comment: Azure B2C seems the way to go in my opinion, have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The customization options of Azure AD are limited to branding and some text fields. Azure AD B2C offers much more UI customization options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization.

It works by you providing a link to the HTML you would like to use on the page. You will need to put a single empty div element there though, where B2C will insert its content. You can use CSS to customize how they look. JavaScript is not allowed though for security reasons.

Though this probably should not be your decision point when deciding between Azure AD and Azure AD B2C since they are pretty different products. B2C is meant for customer-facing applications, while Azure AD is for apps used by organizations.

Comment: Javascript is allowed in b2c pages. You just have to enable it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples.

Answer (score 1):

I found this,

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/

Basically you want to be able to authenticate with Azure AD directly and pass the token to the signed in user.

Looks like the code you need is in the file

> ⁨active-directory-dotnet-native-headless-master⁩/TodoListClient⁩/Program.cs

Hope it helps